# When running mvn versions:set, any way to automatically suppress the effect on unmodified code?

Tags: git, maven

I'm working on a large system with several projects and modules, and sometimes I need to do a `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=...` to bump up the version number. I'd like to be able to do this globally (looping over all projects in a script), but I don't want to bump up the version on modules that have not been modified (e.g. there are no commits and no workspace changes since the last time the version was bumped).

What's the simplest way to accomplish this?